# Why sscanf doesn't work well in this code?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char string[80]="abcdef";
    char buffer[80];
    int num;
    sscanf(string,"%*[^0-9a-fA-F]%n%s",&num,buffer);
    printf("%d\n",num);
    puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-149278720
```

And what I expect is

```
0
abcdef
```

I believe that the regex `%*[^0-9a-fA-F]` discards all characters other than `"xdigits"`, however, when the first character in the string is a `"xdigit"`, `sscanf` seems to return instantly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you check the return value of `sscanf()`?

Comment: Stackoverflow should auto-reject all posts with unchecked scanf return values.

Comment: @Jens :) well said, sir.

Comment: @Jens But I've used %n

Comment: @Jens 
n Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters consumed thus far from the input is stored through the next pointer, which must be a pointer to int. This is not a conversion, although it can be suppressed with the * assignment-suppression character. The C standard says: "Execution of a %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the comple- tion of execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this. Probably it is wise not to make any assumptions on the effect of %n conversions on the return value. From http://man.he.net/man3/sscanf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%*[^0-9a-fA-F]` matches a **non-empty** sequence of characters that aren't in the character set. Since you don't have any non-hexdigits at the beginning of the string, this conversion fails and `sscanf` returns immediately.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to make this optional in `sscanf`. If you just want to skip over the non-hexdigits, use `strcspn()`.

```
num = strcspn(string, "0123456789abcdefABCDEF");
strcpy(buf, string+num);
```